# ORA-30512: Cannot modify <USER.TABLE> more than once in a transaction

Tags: oracle, plsql

**What i am trying to do**

I am trying to rename a column with the following query:

`alter table audit_schema rename column object to objectname;`.

**What is the problem**

oracle return this strange error `ORA-30512: Cannot modify AHTI.AUDIT_SCHEMA more than once in a transaction` after renaming the column.

**Table:**

```
Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
USERNAME                                           VARCHAR2(30)
CURRENTDATE                                        VARCHAR2(30)
OBJECT                                             VARCHAR2(30)
```

**Trigger:**

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER audit_schema_tr
 AFTER DDL ON Schema
 BEGIN      
        insert into audit_schema values (user, sysdate,ora_dict_obj_type);  
END; 
/
```

Comment: Disable the trigger and try running `rename`. `ALTER TRIGGER audit_schema_tr DISABLE`

Comment: Did you mean `ALTER TRIGGER audit_schema_tr DISABLE `?

Comment: `ALTER TRIGGER audit_schema_tr DISABLE ` does not work however i dropped the trigger and then renamed the column and it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try disabling the trigger and then renaming the column.

```
ALTER trigger trigg_name disable
```

If it doesn't work, drop your `trigger` -

```
DROP Trigger trig_name
```

rename the column and recreate the `trigger`.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a problem if you're trying to audit changes to your audit table. Another solution to this is to add the following to your trigger. This will prevent having to remember to disable/drop the trigger whenever you are modifying it:

```
if (NOT (ORA_DICT_OBJ_NAME = 'AUDIT_SCHEMA') AND
     ORA_DICT_OBJ_TYPE = 'TABLE')) Then
  insert into audit_schema values (user, sysdate,ora_dict_obj_type);  
End if;
```